# Free website blocker for Android tablet

Tags: gratis, android, website-blocker

I should not be able to touch the settings in the specified time frame.

I should be able to add more websites in case I forget to add them in the first go.

I am using Android on a tablet Samsung Galaxy T231, with Chrome on it. I am ready to install Firefox if required.

Comment: Rooted or not rooted?

Comment: haven't rooted nor intend to. @RockPaperLizard

Comment: Did we answer this one, or did you find something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can install applications like [SafeBrowser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudacl) (Does not require root), however, this goes at the question as though you're going to abide by using this as your browser (you could enforce some application lock to ensure this happens, however).

Well, if you [root your Samsung Galaxy T231](http://thetechrism.com/galaxy-tab-4-sm-t231-root-twrp-android-4-4-2/) , through ES File Explorer you can edit your host file. This can be done quite simply, here is a link to the [How To Geek website](http://www.howtogeek.com/140576/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-android-and-block-web-sites/).

Another method as you said was to install Mozilla Firefox and run any one of the numerous add-ons to ensure you can block a website, however, against his relies on the user accessing only Firefox.

I'm quite sure with Tasker you can create a trigger to make changes to your Host file, or perhaps use IP Tables via [AFWall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudacl)+ to simply create application triggers and not website triggers.

Comment: Or setup a DNS server (eg. `dnsmasq`) on another device (eg. on a Raspberry Pi) and set that as the default DNS server on the tablet...

Comment: Relies on device being DNS st home and work, assuming needing a more basic setup.